# how do i get selective tag from html body through cURL?

Tags: php, curl

PHP

```
$ch = curl_init() ;
$url = "http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/index.html" ;
$options = array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_HEADER => false ,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false ,
     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options) ;
curl_exec($ch) ;
curl_close($ch);
```

this code execute the page of uefa which i don't want . i just want to access only some information from html body so how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to inspect the webpage and locate the div or the table or any other tag you want. This is a example for getting all the information from a div

```
$ch = curl_init() ;
$url = "http://www.uefa.com/uefaeuro/index.html" ;
$options = array(
     CURLOPT_URL => $url,
     CURLOPT_HEADER => false ,
     CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
     CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false ,
     CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10
); 

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options) ;
$values = curl_exec($ch) ;
curl_close($ch); 

preg_match_all("/<div class=\"put the div class\">(.*?)<\/div>/i",$values ,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Preg_mach will store all the data that is between the div "(.*?)" and store it in $matches variable. 
If you print the "$matches" you will print all the values that's in the div you have chosen. You can do the same think for all tags. I hope it helps you :)

Comment: but page of uefa i still open first . how to avoid or hide that page